# Sublist included in a larger list

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

(I am not sure how to represent the following, so that's part of the question)

I have an ordered list $L$ of typed objects: $< a_x, b_x, c_y, d_y, e_x >$ (where *x* and *y* represent the types). Based on the types, I can extract two sublists $L_x$ and $L_y$ : $<a_x, b_x, e_x>$ and $<c_y, d_y>$.

Now the questions:

1) How can I express inclusion and say that $L_x$ is part of $L$ ($\in$ seems intuitively wrong here).

2) How do I express that $L$ is a product of $L_x$ and $L_y$ (list concatenation is clearly wrong).

3) What can I read to get a better undersanding of these elements? would this be a special case of ordered pairs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that by typing you mean that $a_x, b_x, e_x \in X$ and $c_y, d_y \in Y$.

By definition an ordered list of elements of S is in set terms a sequence (finite or infinite) , i.e. a mapping from (a subset of) the positive integers to S. i.e. a set of ordered pairs 
{ $(n, s): n \in $ (a subset of) $ N $ and $ s \in S $}.

In your case this is complicated by having elements chosen from $X$ and $Y$, so that $S = X \cup Y$. A further complication is that perhaps  $X \cap Y \ne \emptyset$, but you still wish to be able to identify whether an element comes from $X$ or $Y$.

To retain the identity, form the Cartesian products $X \times 'X'$ and $Y \times 'Y'$ and then take their union, $S = X \times 'X' \cup Y \times 'Y'$ which will then include elements (from your example) $(a, X), (b, X), (c, Y), (d, Y), (e, X)$.

Now you can define a sequence mapping (a subset of) the positive integers to S and end up with **a set** $ L = \{(1, (a, X)), (2,(b, X)), (3,(c, Y)), (4,(d, Y)), (5,(e, X))\}$ which represents your ordered list. Since this is **a set**, you can apply set logic to it and say

1. $L_x = \{l \in L : l = (f, (g, h))$ and $ h = 'X'\}$.
2. Similarly $L_y = \{l \in L : l = (f, (g, h))$ and $ h = 'Y'\}$. and now $L = L_x \cup L_y$.

Others may give you some references, but my own "bible" for this subject is Halmos's Naive Set Theory.

---

Sorry I couldn't get the notation as clear as I wished. The Cartesian product $X \times 'X'$  just means the set of ordered pairs $(x, $'$X')$consisting of an element $x \in X$ and the literal "X". This allows you to distinguish between $(c, $'$X')$ and $(c, $'$Y')$ so that you know if the $c$ in question comes from $X$ or $Y$. When you then form the list you end up with elements of a **set** of the form $(f, (g, h))$ where $f \in$ (a subset of) $N$; $g \in X \cup Y$ and $h = $ the literal value "X" or "Y" to tell you where the element came from. Then when you specify $L_x = \{l \in L : l = (f, (g, h))$ and $h = $'$X'\}$ you are selecting those elements that came from X

Comment: It looks like what I am looking for.  Could you clarify what $\times{}', ='$ and $Y'$ mean? I thought ' meant complement of...

Comment: Added notes on this - too large for comment.